# Debugging structural equality "problems"

Tags: f#, equality

I have `e : Expr` and a function that traverses and mutates the expression, let's name it `transform`.
I apply `transform` twice in `e` and get `e1` and `e2`.

As a surprise for me: `e1 <> e2`.

For simpler expressions the equality holds!

How to debug this, is there a general function, utility to help detect the parts of the structures that are different?

Funny: comparing the string output `printfn "%A"` for both expressions => equality.

Comment: If `transform` mutates `e`, then it gets different input the second time, so it's not surprising that it produces different output.

Comment: Most of the expressions are equal. I discovered that comparing two vars with same name and type returns false. But comparing two constant expressions with same value => true. it seems that the equality for Expr descendants is not "proper" ( intuitivly ) implemented.

Comment: Can you show us a working example? With these pieces of information, the problem can be anywhere. Comparing ToString results doesn't prove anything. Does `GetHashCode()` return the same data? I can't see the class implementing `IComparable`, if you want to compare two instances of the class, you maybe want to create a class implementing `IEqualityComparer` to compare them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way `Var` is currently overriding its Equals and GetHashCode methods. Source available [here](http://fsharppowerpack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#compiler/3.1/Nov2013/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/quotations.fs).

```
override v.GetHashCode() = base.GetHashCode()

override v.Equals(obj:obj) = 
    match obj with 
    | :? Var as v2 -> System.Object.ReferenceEquals(v,v2)
    | _ -> false

interface System.IComparable with 
    member v.CompareTo(obj:obj) = 
        match obj with 
        | :? Var as v2 -> 
            if System.Object.ReferenceEquals(v,v2) then 0 else
            let c = compare v.Name v2.Name 
            if c <> 0 then c else 
#if FX_NO_REFLECTION_METADATA_TOKENS // not available on Compact Framework
#else
            let c = compare v.Type.MetadataToken v2.Type.MetadataToken 
            if c <> 0 then c else 
            let c = compare v.Type.Module.MetadataToken v2.Type.Module.MetadataToken 
            if c <> 0 then c else 
#endif
            let c = compare v.Type.Assembly.FullName v2.Type.Assembly.FullName 
            if c <> 0 then c else 
            compare v.Stamp v2.Stamp
        | _ -> 0
```

That means, you will have to implement different ways than the ones that use `Equals()` method on `Var`, as two `Var`s are equal only if they are reference equal.

Comment: I arrived to the same conclusion, that Vars are the cause. My  method certain transforms some values into parameters. I will need to use a scoped cache for Vars. Thanks.